# Javascript or jQuery slide to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When a user clicks on the "Contact Me" button, i want the screen to slide to the #contact element, however cannot figure out how to do it. I've tried various different snippets of code and tried to tailor it to my needs, but nothing seems to work.

The site is here; http://dombracher.com/

Simply want the screen to slide to the div mentioned above, rather than quickly snap to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the versions you already tried and describe what didn't work.

Comment: Hey  @a_maar write that down don't be shy I'll give you vote I'm curios about that approach

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a[href^='#']").anchorAnimate()
});

jQuery.fn.anchorAnimate = function(settings) {

    settings = jQuery.extend({
        speed : 1100
    }, settings);   

    return this.each(function(){
        var caller = this
        $(caller).click(function (event) {  
            event.preventDefault()
            var locationHref = window.location.href
            var elementClick = $(caller).attr("href")

            var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
            $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination}, settings.speed, function() {
                window.location.hash = elementClick
            });
            return false;
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi, i tried this code to no avail. I'm sure your and the other posters code works fine, but it doesn't seem to work when inserting it to my header.php - as usual, it simply jumps to the div instead of sliding. Any advice?

Comment: Loaded jquery before the code, still nothing. Was i supposed to enter additional code to the Javascript?

Answer (score 3):

You can animate window scroll by yourself

```
$(".menu2").click(function(){
    $(document.body).animate({
        "scrollTop": $("#contact").offset().top
    }, 2000, "swing"); // animation time and easing
    return false; // preventing default jump
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M8JE2/

Or use jquery plugin like http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html to make any/all local links work with animation.

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work. I've added the javascript in the header, but nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to wrap this into `$(function(){    });` - here an example http://fiddle.jshell.net/M8JE2/2/show/light/

Comment: When clicking that button on jshell, it doesn't take me to the bottom of the page as it should.

Comment: I tried this again, still with no luck. I put the code, as per the jsfiddle, in my header.php but clicking Contact simply jumps to the div instead of sliding.

Comment: Now on http://dombracher.com/ I get "jQuery is not defined" error in console. Try to put your scrift after you load jQuery (now 41 line in resulting html).

Comment: Weird, this piece of code still does not work. It works fine in the fiddle environment, but whenever i try use it on my server, it simply doesn't work. This code is exactly what i need, the first poster posted javascript that simply goes to the bottom of the document, yours however, takes you to the exact element. If you can help me get this code to work, i'd really appreciate it.

Comment: The code i'm using now is the code posted by Kidwon, however i'd like to use your code so i can have the javascript code work for the first AND second menu items.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is , scrolls to the bottom of the page since your contact form is there:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#nav1 li.menu2').click(function (e) {
        jQuery("html, body").stop().animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery(document).height()
        }, 1000);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I couldn't seem to get this to work. I added the javascript to the header, below the navigation but still no joy. Am i missing something?

Comment: By just posting it you only define it but you never call it to execute! To do so: put the code here `jQuery(function(){the above code placed here});` also the `setActive()` function you are using returns error find it and fix it and last but not least no need to have pair of `<script></script>` tags for each javascript code putting all the code in just one is enough.

Comment: OK, this last update definitely works I've tested it on your site.

Comment: Tried it again and still no joy - what am i doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't loading jquery before the code, d'oh. Works perfectly, exactly what i wanted - thanks!